# Movie or television series about two grandparents losing their grandchildren, who were born to witches

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, witches

I watched this around 1998-2000.
I remember very little and I am not sure if I'm confusing and mixing two items into one.

I am also not sure if it was a movie or a television series. It was very long, so might be a movie, but it ended with 'to be continued' so it might well be a TV series.
It was filmed in the US.

It was about a family, the parents were witches and they were killed by witch hunters. They had two children. Older son about 18, and a young daughter about 5. After their death, the kids were taken in by their grandparents.

At some point, the guy got into a fight and was stabbed (I think) to death. The grandparents took the little girl and ran away to another location to keep her safe.
During their drive, they witness a car crash on the road. When they stop to help the survivors, other witches came out of nowhere, abduct the girl and disappear, apparently the car accident was a scam to get the girl.

Comment: I hesitate to put up an answer yet, but I suspect you *are* conflating 2 plots. The gist sounds like [Blood Ties](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101477/) (1991) about a boy whose parents are killed by *vampire* hunters and contacts his *uncle*, who the hunters then come after. However, there are older relatives at the uncle's, and the hunters treat them like witches (e.g. burning them at the stake). *But there's no little girl, and the last paragraph seems to be from something else entirely.* The movie is on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI56StyEcQI); see if it looks familiar.

Comment: @Walt Thank you but it's not the one. There was definitely a little sister. The scene where she was grabbed and kidnapped from her grandparents (maybe uncle and aunt) is the scene that is most rememberable to me. Also, it was many years later than that.